# The topologist's sine curve is connected but is not path-connecte.

Tags: general-topology

What shown below is a reference from "Topology" by James Munkres

[image]

So I don't understand why $\overline{S}=S\cup\{(0,t)|t\in[-1,1]\}$ and why it is possible to choose $u\in(0,x(\frac{1}n))$ such that $\text{sin}(\frac{1}u)=(-1)^n$ and then why by the intermediate value theorem it follows that there exist $t_n\in(0,\frac{1}n)$ such that $x(t_n)=u$ and so why $t\rightarrow 0$ and $y(t_n)=(-1)^n$. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that $S$ is closed in $(0,+\infty) \times \Bbb R$, because it's just a graph of a continuous function (to a Hausdorff space). So in $\Bbb R^2$ the only new points in the closure can be those with $x=0$, and as $S \subseteq \mathbb R \times [-1,1]$ (which is closed already in the plane), the only candidate new points for the closure are $\{0\} \times [-1,1]$. And they *are* points of $\overline{S}$ because there is, for each $(0,u)$ in that set a sequence of points from $S$ converging to $(0,u)$: let $t_0 \in [-\pi,pi]$ be such that $\sin(t_0) = u$. Then define for all $n \in \Bbb N^+$: $t_n=\frac{1}{t_0 + 2n\pi} \in (0,1)$ and note that $\sin(\frac{1}{t_n}) = \sin t_0 = u$, so that $(t_n, u) \in S$ and $(t_n, u) \to (0,u) \in \overline{S}$.

This is also "clear" from the sketch of the graph: close to $0$ there are infinitely many "periods" of a shrinking sine-graph and all of these assume all values in $[-1,1]$ in shorter and shorter time, the closer we get to $0$. The above argument formalises this idea a bit.

This also makes it clear, hopefully, that the rest of the argument also holds: $(0,p)$ for any $p>0$ contains infinitely many "swings" of the sine-curve.

There is only the minor complication that we have the extra $x(t)$ function but that is continuous, so the intermediate value theorem allows us to mimick the above idea to find the $t_n$ as well.

Comment: Okay, unfortunately I don't understand your first statement: it seems that you say that if $f:X\rightarrow X$ is continuous and if $X$ is $T_2$ then the graph $\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}$ is closed in $X\times X$, right? If this is true, how to prove the statement?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro $f: X \to Y$ and $Y$ Hausdorff . This is a standard fact.

Comment: Hi professor Brandsma, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628022/the-normed-vector-spaces-are-topological-vector-spaces)? Unfortunately I hadn't complete answers.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro come on, try to follow the hint in the given answer!

Comment: I proved it. However I think that if $\Bbb{K}$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$ then the scalar multiplication is not continuous.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro the field is a normed one, usually. Could be the complex numbers too, but the norm on $V$ and $\Bbb K$ should be combined in an axiom.

Comment: Okay, so I'll suppose that even $\Bbb{K}$ is normed.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro that’s part of the definition of a normed space...

Answer (score 1):

I do not find it convenient to replace $[b,c]$ with $[0,1].$

Notation: $f''U=\{f(u): u\in U\}$ when $f$ is a function and $U\subseteq$  dom$(f).$

Let $f(t)=(g(t),\sin 1/g(t))$ for $t\in (b,c].$

For any $t\in (b,c], $ suppose there existed  $x\in (0,g(t))$ with $(x,\sin 1/x)\not \in J_t= f''[b, t].$ Then  $J_t\cap ((-\infty,x)\times \Bbb R)$ and $J_t \cap ((x,\infty)\times \Bbb R)$ would be a " disconnection" of the connected space $J_t,$ which is absurd.

So for  every $t\in (b,c]$ we have $$ (\bullet)\quad f''(b,t)\supset \{(x,\sin 1/x): x\in (0, g(t)\}. $$

Now $(t_n)_n$ is a sequence in $(b,c]$ converging to $b,$ so $(g(t_n))_n$ is a positive sequence converging to $0.$ For each $n,$  take some (large enough) $k_n\in \Bbb N$ such that $0<x'_n<x''_n< g(t_n)$ where $x'_n=(\pi (2k_n+\frac {1}{2}))^{-1}$ and $x''_n=(\pi (2k_n-\frac {1}{2}))^{-1}.$  By $(\bullet)$ there exist $t'_n$ and $t''_n$ in $(b, t_n)$ such that

$f(t'_n)=(x'_n, \sin  1/x'_n)=(x'_n, 1)$

and $f(t''_n)=(x''_n,\sin 1/t''_n)=(x''_n,-1).$

Now $t'_n$ and $t''_n$ both $\to b$ because $t'_n, t''_n\in (b,t_n).$ But $f(t'_n)$ and $f(t''_n)$ cannot converge to the same point, which is absurd if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: The notation $f''U$ is used in Set Theory, where it is common to have both $U\subset$ dom $(f)$ and $U\in$ dom($f)$.