# The normed vector spaces are topological vector spaces.

Tags: general-topology

> **Definition**
>
> Given a vector space $V$ over a field of the real number $\Bbb{R}$ a norm on $V$ is a nonnegative-valued function $\|\cdot\|:V\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ with the following properties:
>
> 1. $\|v\|=0$ iff $v=0$
> 2. $\|r*v\|=|r|\cdot\|v\|$ for any $r\in\Bbb{R}$
> 3. $\|v+w\|\le\|v\|+\|w\|$ for any $v,w\in V$
>
> So if $V$ is a vector space on the field of the real number $\Bbb{R}$ and if $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $V$ we say that $V$ is a normed vector space.
>
> **Statement**
>
> If $V$ is a normed vector space then the function $d:V\times V\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^+\cup\{0\}$ defined through the condition 
>   $$
> d(v,w)=\|v-w\|
> $$
>   for any $v,w\in V$ is a distance in $V$ that induces a metric topology on $V$.
>
> **Definition**
>
> A topological vector space is a vector space over a topological field $\Bbb{K}$ that is endowed with a topology such that vector addition $+:V\times V\rightarrow V$ and scalar multiplication $*:\Bbb{K}\times V\rightarrow V$ are continuous functions.
>
> **Statement**
>
> The normed vector spaces are topological vector spaces.

Unfortunately I can't prove the last statement: using the triangle inequality I attempted to prove that the inverse image of a open set on $V$ through the functions $+$ and $*$ is a open set on $V\times V$ and $\Bbb{K}\times V$, but unfortunately it seems difficult to me. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Do you know what it is that you have to prove?

Comment: You can certainly start the proof. Tell us where you get stuck (if you do) so the we can help.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I attempted to prove that the inverse image of a open set on $V$ through the functions $+$ and $*$ is a open set on $V\times V$ and $\Bbb{K}\times V$, but unfortunately it seems difficult to me. So could you help me, please?

Comment: Normed vector spaces are metric spaces. Try to use open balls to prove that inverse images are open sets. However it is much easier to use sequential form of  continuity.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I tried to do it: exactly I tried to use the triangle inequality but unfortunately it seems difficult to me. Otherwise I didn't put the question.

Comment: Hint: $\|a_nx_n-ax\| \leq \|a_nx_n-a_nx\|+\|a_nx-ax\|=|a_n|\|x_n-x\|+|a_n-a|\|x\|$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I did what you wrote, but I don't understand how I can conclude that $*$ is continuous: so I have to verify that for any nhood $A$ of $*(r,v)$ in $V$ there exist a nhood $B$ of $(r,v)$  in $\Bbb{K}\times V$ such that $*(B)\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vector $v$ in $V$ and any $\delta>0$ denote by $B_\delta(v)$ the open ball centered at $v$ with radius $\delta$, i.e. the set of vectors $w$ such that $d(w,v)=||w-v||<\delta$.

By definition of the metric topology, a subset $U$ of $V$is open if for all $v \in U$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $B_\delta(v) \subset U$.

So, if $A : V \times V \to V$ denotes the addition map $+$ and $U$ is an open subset of $V$, we can consider any point $(x,y) \in A^{-1}(U)$. If we can show that there are open sets $A_x$ and $A_y$ containing $x$ and $y$, respectivly, such that $A_x \times A_y \subset A^{-1}(U)$, then $A$ will be continuous (right?). But by assumption, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $B_\delta(x+y) \subset U$.

Now it would be nice if we could find a $\delta'>0$ such that $B_{\delta'}(x) \times B_{\delta'}(y) \subset A^{-1}(B_\delta(x+y))$, because that would provide us with such sets $A_x$ and $A_y$. Using the triangle-inequality, can you see what $\delta'$ you could use?

Comment: Okay, so let be $\delta':=\frac{\delta}2$ and so we observe that if $h \in B_{\delta'}(x)$ and $k\in B_{\delta'}(y)$ then it follows that $||(x+y)-(h+k)||=||(x-h)+(y-k)||\le||x-h||+||y-k||\le 2\delta'=\delta$ and so clearly $A\Big(B_{\delta'}(x)\times B_{\delta'}(y)\Big)\subseteq B_\delta(x+y)\subseteq U$, form which we can conclude that the vector sum is continuous. However how to prove that even the scalar multiplication $*:\Bbb{K}\times V\rightarrow V$ is continuous? Could you prove it, please?

Comment: As in the previous proof let be $U$ and open set in $V$ and so we consider $(r,w)\in A^{-1}(U)$, where $A:=*$; then we suppose that $\Bbb{K}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$. So now we consider $B_\delta(r*w)$ and we find and open basic set $B_{\delta'}(r)$ in $\Bbb{R}$ and an open basic set $B_{\delta'}(w)$ and so we prove that $A\Big(B_{\delta'}(r)\times B_{\delta'}(w)\Big)\subseteq B_\delta(r*w)$.

Comment: So let be $k\in B_{\delta'}(r)$ and $v\in B_{\delta'}(w)$ and choosing $\delta'$ such that 
$\delta'(||w|+|r|)+(\delta')^2<\delta$ we observe that 
$$||r*w-k*v||=||r*w-k*w+k*w-k*v||\le|r-k|\cdot||w||+|k|\cdot||w-v||<\delta'(||w||+|k|)\le\delta'(||w||+|k-r|+|r|)<\delta'(||w||+|r|)+(\delta')^2<\delta
$$
and so we conclude that the scalar multiplication $*$ is continuous.

Comment: Anyway if $\Bbb{K}$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$, is still the statement true?